# Are there any elements within the interval $(0,0)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If the interval $(0,0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, is it necessarily an empty set?

Is this the case for any interval defined by $a \in \mathbb{R}, (a,a)$?

*(This is not a question for or from any homework or assignment.)*

Comment: What is your definition of a set of the form $(a,b)$ for real numbers $a,b$?

Comment: I did say that I defined a set $(a,b)$ to be an interval that is a subset of the real numbers, but I will go by Henno Brandsma's definition that $(a,b)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any elements $a,b$ of the ordered set we have *by definition*:

$$(a,b)= \{x \in \Bbb R: a < x \text{ and } x < b\}$$

and so for $a=0,b=0$ the condition on $x$ becomes $x>0$ and $x <0$ which is impossible by trichotomy. So $(0,0)=\emptyset$ indeed. Same for any $(a,a)$.